# NSDateFormatter string to date conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert

```
3/27/2015 5:45:00 AM
```

string into an NSDate object.

I tried this;

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

but it does not work.

What might be wrong that i could not figure out?

Thanks

Code added;

```
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
      [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];  
      NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3/27/2015 5:45:00 AM"]
```

EDIT:

It is somehow, because of time slice(AM/PM) gets null.
I removed "a" from dateformatter and AM from the string. it is OK.
But still do not know what is wrong with "a" ?

Comment: have you tried "m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"? as far as I know date are digit sensitive and your month only has one digit, you should use 03/.. 05:..

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? With your format `[dateFromatter dateFromString:@"3/27/2015 5:45:00 AM"]` gives me correct output.

Comment: @JakubVano i do not get the correct input , my date is nil

Comment: @erdemgc can you post the entire code that gives you wrong result?

Comment: @JakubVano i have added the code, i have written the string hard-coded but tempDate is still nil

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the add the locale for the date locale to the date formatter.
The code will run fine an any device set to US english, but other locales will fail. Just add the `en_US_POSIX` as the locale for the date formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3/27/2015 5:45:00 AM"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3/27/2015 5:45:00 AM"];
NSLog(@"%@", tempDate); // prints "2015-03-27 09:45:00 +0000" to the console.
```

This is the code that you have posted. I copied it verbatim. The `NSLog` that I included correctly prints a date and not `nil`.

Comment: when i copy and paste that piece of code, the output is nil